# What is Spring KafkaListener reading strategy with severals topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

How Kafka works with severals topics?

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = {"topic1" , "topic2"}, groupId = "groupid")
```

For example:

- "topic1" has "topic1_message1","topic1_message2" entities on a single partition
- "topic2" has "topic2_message1","topic2_message2" entities on a single partition

What will be the reading order?

- "topic1_message1","topic1_message2","topic2_message1","topic2_message2"
- "topic1_message1","topic2_message1","topic1_message2","topic2_message2"

Or server will instanciate two threads which are reading both topics concurently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both of these are true. it is randomly

- "topic1_message1","topic1_message2","topic2_message1","topic2_message2"
- "topic1_message1","topic2_message1","topic1_message2","topic2_message2"

because they are on single partition one thing you should know;

1. "topic1_message1" comes before "topic1_message2"
2. "topic2_message1" comes before "topic2_message2"

Comment: There is one thread only (unless you increase `concurrency`). The records will be delievered in the order they arrive from the broker(s), which is indeterminate - the topics might be on different broker instances. Order within a partition is guaranteed.